# Magneto 2: Different countries in billing and shipping address

Tags: magento2.3.1, shipping-address, billing-address

How to limit the countries in the shipping address, for example, I want to allow all countries in billing address but only one in the shipping address( at the moment). Any idea how to achieve this in Magento 2.3.1 community ..

Comment: I think it is not possible. You can add validation to indicate a user only particular shipping country is allowed.

Comment: thanks aravind, but i am sure, there will be a way to do that .. where we can set billing and shipping countries from the back end ..

Answer (score 8):

For show only one country in shipping address country dropdown we have to create plugin of `LayoutProcessor` method for override `country_id` children field of `shipping-address-fieldset` which we found in `module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` file.

registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Trecks_Checkoutcountry',
    __DIR__
);
```

etc/module.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Trecks_Checkoutcountry" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

etc/frontend/di.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="Treckslayoutprocessor" type="Trecks\Checkoutcountry\Plugin\LayoutProcessor"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Plugin/LayoutProcessor.php:-

Here you can put different countries code in `$countryIds` of `getCountryOptions()` for show particular countries in dropdown.

```
<?php

namespace Trecks\Checkoutcountry\Plugin;
use Magento\Directory\Helper\Data as DirectoryHelper;

class LayoutProcessor
{

    protected $countryOptions;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory $countryCollection,
        DirectoryHelper $directoryHelper
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->countryCollectionFactory = $countryCollection;
        $this->directoryHelper = $directoryHelper;
    }

   
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        $result
    ) {

        $result['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['country_id'] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/select',
                'id' => 'drop-down',
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.country_id',
            'label' => 'Country',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' => [],
            'sortOrder' => 70,
            'id' => 'drop-down',
            'options' => $this->getCountryOptions()
        ];
        return $result;
    }

    public function getStoreId()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    }

    //We have refernce this function from Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessor
    public function getCountryOptions()
    {
            $countryIds = array("US");
            //$countryIds = array("US","CA");
           
            $countryselection = $this->countryCollectionFactory->create()->loadByStore(
                $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
            $countryselection->addFieldToFilter('country_id', ['in' => $countryIds]);
            $countryselection = $countryselection->toOptionArray();
            $countryarray = $this->orderCountryOptions($countryselection);

        return $countryarray;
    }


    public function orderCountryOptions(array $countryOptions)
    {
        $topCountryCodes = $this->directoryHelper->getTopCountryCodes();
        if (empty($topCountryCodes)) {
            return $countryOptions;
        }

        $headOptions = [];
        $tailOptions = [[
            'value' => 'delimiter',
            'label' => '──────────',
            'disabled' => true,
        ]];
        foreach ($countryOptions as $countryOption) {
            if (empty($countryOption['value']) || in_array($countryOption['value'], $topCountryCodes)) {
                $headOptions[] = $countryOption;
            } else {
                $tailOptions[] = $countryOption;
            }
        }
        return array_merge($headOptions, $tailOptions);
    }
}
```

Hope it works. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Raj , it works perfectly for me with few changes.

Comment: Thanks Raj.. You saved my time

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is currently possible to achieve through configuration in Magento 2.3, see this [github issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5775) for reference. It is possible to allow all countries for shipping and restrict the payment methods based on country, but not vice versa. A Magento extension would have to be implemented (or purchased) to achieve this behaviour. I am unsure of any 3rd party extensions that provide this.